# Can't install homebrew or update Ruby on OS X

Tags: ruby, homebrew, macos-high-sierra, dyld

I have a problem with installing Homebrew on OS X. OS version is **High Sierra 10.13.3**

Trying to run:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

It returns:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/libruby.2.3.0.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/bin/ruby
Reason: Incompatible library version: ruby requires version 2.3.3 or later, but libruby.2.3.0.dylib provides version 2.3.0
Abort trap: 6
```

People saying to update Ruby via **rvm** or **rbenv**, but no success with them.

Trying this:

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/archive/1.29.3.tar.gz
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.29.3/1.29.3.tar.gz.asc
Found PGP signature at: 'https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.29.3/1.29.3.tar.gz.asc',
but no GPG software exists to validate it, skipping.

Upgrading the RVM installation in /Users/m1-user/.rvm/
RVM PATH line found in /Users/m1-user/.mkshrc /Users/m1-user/.profile /Users/mm-user/.bashrc /Users/mm-user/.zshrc.
RVM sourcing line found in /Users/m1-user/.profile /Users/mm-user/.zlogin.
RVM sourcing line not found for Bash, rerun this command with '--auto-dotfiles' flag to fix it.
Upgrade of RVM in /Users/m1-user/.rvm/ is complete.

Upgrade Notes:

  * No new notes to display.
```

And after it:

```
$ rvm install ruby-2.4.1
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.13/x86_64/ruby-2.4.1.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
About to install Homebrew, press `Enter` for default installation in `/usr/local`,
type new path if you wish custom Homebrew installation (the path needs to be writable for user)
: 
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/libruby.2.3.0.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/bin/ruby
Reason: Incompatible library version: ruby requires version 2.3.3 or later, but libruby.2.3.0.dylib provides version 2.3.0
Requirements installation failed with status: 134.
```

So it's like a vicious circle: I cannot install homebrew because of ruby old version, and I cannot update ruby because I need to install homebrew.

Any help?

Comment: Kind of a last resort, but you can always try installing from source. Though without homebrew you will probably have to install some dependencies from source as well. At the very least I would think you need `autoconf`. If you don't know how to do that I can leave an answer with some steps.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of searching, I did not find the right solution. But I tried to update Ruby by compiling it myself. And it worked for me. So maybe it will help somebody too.

Firstly you need to download Ruby sources from https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/ You can choose any stable version. I downloaded 2.5.0.

Then extract the archive and copy it to Ruby folder:

```
# Replace path below to correct path to extracted folder
sudo cp -r /Users/your-user/Downloads/ruby-2.5.0 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/
```

Then change directory to the copied folder:

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/ruby-2.5.0
```

Then you should compile it by running next commands:

```
sudo ./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Then you can list available Ruby versions and choose one to install:

```
# Will list available versions
rvm list known
# Choose from available and install it
rvm install ruby-2.4.1
```

After that Homebrew was installed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you'll need to uninstall ruby and then try to install Homebrew.  Once Homebrew is working you can reinstall ruby.  RVM requires Homebrew according to this http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html

Comment: Homebrew need ruby to be installed